# How can I filter unique values in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react, so be please be gentle. 
I have a relatively flat JS file that contains some questions. It looks like this:

```
export default [
{
  category: 'General Questions',
  title: 'Question 1?',
  content:'Answer 1',
},
{
  category: 'Pricing',
  title: 'Question 2?',
  content:'Answer 2',
},
```

I have multiple categories throughout the file. What I'd like to do is create a list of all the unique categories. So the user would only see

- General Questions
- Pricing
- Etc.

I'm able to get all of the content using a `filter` function here:

```
getFaqContent() {
    return filter(item => {
        return item.featured;
    }, Faqs);
}
```

How can I just get the unique categories?

Comment: Just a quick note, you can use much smaller syntax when writing that filter: `Faqs.filter(item => item.featured)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` again to just select the unique categories (Grabbed from some help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)):

```js
const questions = [
{
  category: 'General Questions',
  title: 'Question 1?',
  content:'Answer 1',
},
{
  category: 'Pricing',
  title: 'Question 2?',
  content:'Answer 2',
},
{
  category: 'Pricing',
  title: 'Question 2?',
  content:'Answer 2',
}];

const cats = questions.map(q => q.category);

console.log(
  cats.filter((q, idx) => 
    cats.indexOf(q) === idx)
);
```

Additionally, you can use ES6's new [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) functionality as well, and convert it back to an array using [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const questions = [
{
  category: 'General Questions',
  title: 'Question 1?',
  content:'Answer 1',
},
{
  category: 'Pricing',
  title: 'Question 2?',
  content:'Answer 2',
},
{
  category: 'Pricing',
  title: 'Question 2?',
  content:'Answer 2',
}];

const cats = [...new Set(questions.map(q => q.category))];

console.log(cats);
```

Comment: This works great! I can console all the unique cats. However, I'm getting an error when printing them out: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.  Is it because I don't have a UID for each question?

Comment: Set your key to the value (Should be unique anyway)

Comment: I got it using the `map` method

Comment: See this for more info on the key prop: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution using ES6:

```
const categories = yourList.map(x => x.category);
const uniqueCategories = [...new Set(categories)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()`  you can call `uniqueBy(array, 'category')` where `array` will be your data

```
function uniqueBy(arr, prop){
   return arr.reduce((a, d) => {
   if (!a.includes(d[prop])) { a.push(d[prop]); }
      return a;
   }, []);
} 

var categories = uniqueBy(array, 'category')
console.log(ages); //['General Questions', 'Pricing'  ]
```